# CKEditor not setting configuration

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm loading CKEditor from its CDN, and then using an additional file to change default configuration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.3.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/config.js"></script>
```

My config file looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For the complete reference:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // we don't want too have in a basic editor. We remove them here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Let's have it basic on dialogs as well.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
};
```

Actually I inherited this application from a previous developer, and I'm trying to move to a CDN rather than having to manually download the files for every installation.

I tried removing the configs out of the function too, and then accessing them directly like so:

```
CKEDITOR.config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
```

.. but that didn't work either.

I don't get any errors in console, and when I do `console.log(CKEDITOR)` I can see that the object is there. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CDN-loaded CKEditor does not know that you want to provide it with a custom configuration and uses its own default one instead. You should define the [`config.customConfig`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-customConfig) configuration option pointing to your custom configuration file, as explained on the [CKEditor CDN](http://cdn.ckeditor.com#configuration) site.